# Dynamically object creation Django get_or_create()

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. So I was exploring it a little bit where I find a method get_or_create() for a model.
I am wondering if it is possible like in the Django form. I have a field name category and it is just an input field like Charfield.

So whenever user writes a new article I want the suggestions from the previous categories and if it is not there then it should make a new one on the basis of current one.

Can anyone suggest me some logic or example.

Comment: You mean https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create?

Comment: Sir, @DanielRoseman, I would like to give you an example of the github where if we want to create a new branch then we search it otherwise it automatically get created when we type the name in the search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want [Select-2](https://select2.org/) for django:
[Django-Select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) or [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light)?

Comment: I don't know the functionality of the django-select2, can you please elaborate further ?

Comment: Let me know if I understand you correctly: you want a field that autocompletes text the user is typing into it by checking that text against data already present in the database. And if no data matches, new data based on the text should be created? That is what Select2 can do.   I would say, try the tutorial of django-autocomplete-light. It's not difficult to set up.